# What goes wrong in this conditional probability calculation?

Tags: probability

The probability of $a$ given $x$, where $x \sim U[0,1]$, is given by a function $$s(x) = (1+x^2)/2$$

I calculate $Pr(x|a)$ with Bayes' rule ($f(y) = 1\ \forall y \in [0,1]$ for the uniform distribution and hence drops out):

$$Pr(x|a) = \frac{Pr(a|x) f(x)}{\int_0^1 Pr(a|y) f(y) dy} = \frac{s(x)}{\int_0^1 s(y) dy}$$

$$ \int_0^1 s(y) dy = \frac{(x + x^3/3)
}{2}\bigg|_0^1= 2/3$$

and furthermore $s(1) = 1$, so

$$ Pr(1|a) = 3/2$$

which seems to be an exceptionally likely event.

What goes wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong thing is to write $ Pr(x\mid a)$ instead of $ p(x\mid a)$, or perhaps  $f_{X\mid a}(x\mid a)$. See, $a$ is an event, so it's ok to speak of $Pr(a)$ or $Pr(a \mid x)$. But $x$ is a continuous variable, it does not make much sense to speak of $Pr(x)$ or $Pr(x \mid a)$ (the probability that $x$ takes a particular value is zero).

What you get by Bayes rule is

$$p(x \mid a)= \frac{s(x)}{2/3}=\frac{3}{4} (1+x^2)$$

That's not a probability but a density function, hence its values can well exceed 1. What you can check is that its integral is 1.